# how to bugtest facebook apps in private?

Tags: facebook, public, privacy

I'm just trying to develope a facebook app, so sorry if this question is quite simple. I've set up my App, then entered the canvas URL and thought I could test the app and fiddle around with it in private without anyone knowing. But there was immediately a "is using 'hisnewpp'" message going around or something. Of course I didn't want that since the app is not finished. I couldn't find a setting anywhere, where I could set the app to be public or private.

So in short: where can I call up and test my App on Facebook, without it beeing accessable to anyone else?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to enable sandbox mode in your application's advanced settings. Only you will see the updates then.

Answer (score 0):

Use test users - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ 
You can create temporary or long term test accounts specifically for testing your app - either via the API or in the app settings. You can also place the app in sandbox mode and only developers or testers of the app can interact with the app and/or see the content it produces